# Rails: find parents with children not having an attribute

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, psql

```
 - Invoice has_many Item
 - Item belongs_to Invoice
```

I'm trying to find all invoices that do not have items in status 0, 1 or 2.

Example:

```
Invoice 1
Items:
  Item 1 - status 0
  Item 2 - status 8


Invoice 2
Items:
  Item 1 - status 6
  Item 2 - status 8
```

The query should return Invoice 2 because no one of it's items has a status in [0, 1, 2].

I tried this but it does not work:

```
Invoice.includes(:items).where.not(items: { status: [0, 1, 2] })
```

but it does not work. It keeps returning invoices having items with forbidden statuses.

Comment: Invoice.where(id: Item.where.not(status: [0,1,2]).pluck('invoice_id'))

Comment: is it possible to have 1 SQL query and not two ?

Comment: in fact the db is huge and plucking takes lot of time.

Comment: @Yassine Should be `select('invoice_id')` not `pluck`, my bad

Comment: What's the SQL query for `Invoice.includes(:items).where.not(items: { status: [0, 1, 2] })
` being generated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query should do the trick:

```
Invoice.joins(:items).where("items.status NOT IN (0, 1, 2)")
```

The SQL generated would probably be something like:

```
SELECT "invoices".* 
FROM "invoices" 
INNER JOIN "items" 
ON "items"."invoice_id" = "invoices"."id" 
WHERE (items.status NOT IN (1, 2, 3))
```